# Set selected value in dynamically created combo boxes

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have created dynamic combo boxes but i am not able to set the value of the combo box

```
    var list = new List<string>() { "Add","Sub","Mul","Div"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
         var c = new ComboBox();    
         c.DataSource = list.ToList();
         c.selectedvalue="Sub";
         this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(c);
      }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: no error.....all comboxes default to first item in the list ..i.e Add

Comment: Try c.selectedindex = 0;

Comment: got error .. InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the DataSource of your ComboBox and trying to set the SelectedValue but for this to work correctly you need to set the `ValueMember` to the name of a member property of your datasource. But, in your case, having a simple list of strings, you cannot use any meaningful property name for SelectedValue.

Change your code to

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "Add","Sub","Mul","Div"};
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var c = new ComboBox();
    c.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());
    c.SelectedIndex = 1;
    this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(c);
}
```

Of course you could make this more generic using the IndexOf("Sub") to retrieve the index and replace the fixed 1 that I have used, but in this case it seems useless.

Answer (score 0):

To select a default value of a combobox use the below code.

```
     c.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

This will set the start position at the first item in your list.